# 2000 Yamaha R1 Quick Action Throttle

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, throttle

I've 2000 Yamaha R1 that I'm racing in my local Clubman's Championship. At the moment the throttle travel is very long, ie. half a turn or more from fully closed to fully open. I want to change this to a quick throttle, ie. a 1/4 turn from fully closed to fully open.

You can buy a quick throttle kit, but this is both very expensive and not available for my relatively old bike. Could I fit a throttle tube from a different bike to accomplish this and if so which bike?

Thanks in advance
Willem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your bike specifics you may be able to make one yourself with the method described at this site http://www.aussiestreetbikes.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24848

You'll have to take into account the required additional length of cable, tighter turns that the cable has to route through, you may also have to loosen the cable at the throttlebody/carb end to allow it to idle normally on closed throttle and then open faster.

Comment: Wow, makes me wonder why an actual "kit" is so expensive.  Looks like an easy mod.